# Neo4j search takes +30 min while using 75%CPU 80GB of Ram

Tags: neo4j

Queries in Neo4jShell are really slow and the CPU just goes to around 80% and keeps going. I checked schema: and have indexes. The computer has 128GB Ram and Neo4j is using 75GB of RAM. The database size is 24GB.  There are about 4 million nodes and 120 million relationships

Does anyone know if Neo4j can handle queries with 24GB of data quickly ?

This query takes 20 minutes to return

```
MATCH (o:Foo {rbt:"local-foo"} )-[:val]->(j:Bar )

:schema
Indexes
  ON :Object(text)               ONLINE  
  ON :Foo(rbt)           ONLINE  
  ON :Bar(rbt)         ONLINE  
  ON :Property(prd)        ONLINE  
  ON :PI(rbt) FAILED  

No constraints
```

From my neo4j.properties:

```
# Default values for the low-level graph engine

neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=2999M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=15500M
neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db.mapped_memory=800M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=390M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=330M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=330M
```

Comment: Can you output your query plan? With `profile MATCH (o:Foo {rbt:"local-foo"} ) with o limit 10 match (o)-[:val]->(j:Bar ) return j`

Comment: Which version of Neo4j do you use?

Comment: What kind of disk do you have? What is your config for the memory/heap for neo4j?

Comment: if you have 2.2. you can also use EXPLAIN which doesn't execute the query but just plan it.

Comment: I'm using Neo version 2.2.0 (64-bit) . The database is on a 256GB SSD drive. In my neo4j-community.vmoptions I have one line that says "-Xmx51200m"  Here is an image of what EXPLAIN showed:  http://i.imgur.com/oZwrPjD.png

Comment: Easy, your index is not used.

Comment: can you share your full query? your fragment is not working code

Comment: Can you expand your plan too? Perhaps you just have a typo in the name somewhere?

Comment: Did you run into any issues when creating the indexes? One is shown as "FAILED", can you drop and re-recreate the :Foo(rbt) index? And check graph.db/messages.log if there are any errors? (Just in case).

Comment: Also you should not configure memory mapping like that anymore in Neo4j 2.2.0 there is dbms.pagecache.size=24G as the only setting (or whatever size your store-files are roughly)

Comment: Could you share your graph.db/messages.log ? Send me an email -> michael at neo4j.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with M. Hunger to resolve the situation by modifying indexes and heap management for my system. Queries were sub-second after working through issues.

Comment: sorry for bringing back this from the dead but can you share your solution? at least guidelines? 
I'm having a similar scenario (graph.db directory is around 80GB, server with 128GB mem, seems to upload everything to memory and indexes ar online but even simple queries take an hour or so..)

Answer (score 1):

What about this query ?

```
MATCH (o:Foo {rbt:"local-foo"} )
MATCH (o)-[:val]->(j:Bar)
```

Also, if you are sure that all the **j** nodes will have a **:Bar** label, you can omit it to improve the query :

```
MATCH (o:Foo {rbt:"local-foo"} )
MATCH (o)-[:val]->(j)
```

Comment: Didnt work. Tried the query your way, but it hasnt returned yet. Cpu is at 30%, and its been about 10 min. I reallyhope Neo4j is better than this !!